# Proper way to structure java web app on tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, web-applications

I have developed a web app using java as a "hobby project" over the past few years.  Its basically an order entry and sales order management system for a niche industry I am in.  I have been running the app for 2 clients now for a year, but other clients have expressed interest in using the app.

The application itself works well, but I am worrying about growing pains at this point.  Currently, I point two client domains to my server, where a single tomcat instance runs two identical web apps that each connect to their own MySQL database via hibernate.

I would like to switch these clients and future clients over to a single domain name, where each client would have their own unique sub-domain.

I have a couple related questions that I am trying to answer:

**Is it a good idea to run a single instance of tomcat on each subdomain/client app?**

I don't want to have to interrupt service for each client everytime I need to restart tomcat for application updates.  Also, if I did something wrong with an update I wouldn't want all of my clients to crash at the same time. I imagine this will be resource intensive but the subscription for the app will be between $100-200 / month so I can afford additional hosting when the time comes.

**Is there any reason to use Jboss/ Glassfish as opposed to Tomcat if I don't need the EE features?**

Tomcat seemed easy enough to configure with a simple configuration, but as I move to a more complex deployment would another container be better?

Any point in the right direction would be helpful!  I don't know a whole lot about setting up servers like this since I never had to up until now... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Ideally, you should use (redundant) load balancers, and two (redundant) servers, so that you can stop/restart/reload one of the servers, and still allow clients to connect. You could also have separate staging servers that are identical to the production servers, so that you can make sure things don't crash in production.
2. You can [hot-deploy](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html) on tomcat without restarting it, btw.
3. You can run distinct [tomcat instances](http://www.shaunabram.com/multiple-tomcat-instances/) in their own JVMs so that if one crashes it doesn't affect the other.